# Like buttons in iPhone app

Tags: ios, ios4, facebook

Im working on a app in which will display RSS feeds. The feeds are showed in a tableview.

Here comes the tricky part, I would like to add a fb "like" button in every cell so that the user can like his favourite feed.

And then it should display on facebook something like "XX like this YY-feed".

Is this possible? Any ideas how to approach this problem would be much appreciated?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is possible to achive. However it won't be a smooth solution. I would recommend to use share instead....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method I have played with is adding a tiny WebView to each item, and loading the Facebook liking code in there. I haven't gotten it down quite yet(I am working on something similar), but I thought I would offer this idea.

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is the code you should use, and programatically loading the appropriate values (for step 1) should be straightforward.

Comment: Well, the problem with this solution is to handle the login I guess. The FB Like button also is quite small, wonder if Apple approves of it...